# Does the hardware acceleration framework in IOS simulator reflect what it does on a real iphone?

Tags: ios, image-processing, signal-processing, accelerate-framework

I have been playing with image processing in IOS. Since I want to do everything with my own code other than libraries like openCV, I am exploring all ways to accelerate my program. I do have a huge amount of float calculation, so I am really interested in making use of the DSP.

However, when I compared the results of my straight-forward code using CPU (written in c++) and the vDSP on doing large matrix multiplication on a simulator, I am surprised to see that vDSP consumes significantly more time. The matrices are about 1 million x 6 and 6 x 2, then the CPU and the vDSP takes about 120ms and 180ms, respectively.

I understand I should test everything on a real device and I am certainly going to do that. But I would love to learn more about the reasons and implications. **How does the IOS simulator simulate the DSP? What about GPU (openGL)?**

Much appreciated, forks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The CPU instruction sets, short vector acceleration (for vDSP), and GPU architectures are very different between iOS devices and Simulators on x86 Macs.  There are also vast (10X or more) differences in performance between different iOS device models as as well.  Some iOS devices are faster than Simulators on some Macs at some micro-benchmarks; some are far slower.

Comment: But even being tested on a real iPhone6, the DSP is still no faster than CPU! Just the float-point matrix multiplication costs CPU 390ms or DSP (vDSP_mmul) 415ms, with same results. Is there something I missed? Like special configurations to enable hardware acceleration or so?